# Are 2 quadrilaterals similar if they are both inscribed and have congruent angles and have perp diagonals

Tags: geometry, proof-verification, euclidean-geometry, alternative-proof

This is problem 365 from Kiselev's Planimetry book. I have to show that two inscribed quadrilaterals with perpendicular diagonals are similar iff they have respectively congruent angles. Here is my proof which I believe may have a mistake:

[image]

Let $FCEB$ and $GHIJ$ be the respective quadrilaterals. If they are similar then by definition they have congruent angles, so lets jump to the second part: assume they have respectively congruent angles. Since they both have perpendicular diagionals I can pick up $GHIJ$ and superimpose it so that the intersection of the diagonals coincide and the diagonals lie on the same lines as shown in the diagram. Then if we translate $GHIJ$ by the vector $GF$, the image of $JH$ would become parallel to $BC$ and thus $\frac{GJ}{FB} = \frac{GH}{FC}= \frac{JH}{BC}$. Finally, if we translate $GHIJ$ by the vector $IE$ we have $\frac{IJ}{EB} = \frac{IH}{EC} = \frac{JH}{BC}$ and we see that these equaltions of ratios are connected by $\frac{JH}{BC}$ from where it follows that the quadrilaterals are similar.

Here is a diagram showing what happens after $GHIJ$ is translated.$FH'J'$ and $FCB$ are similar from where the ratio equalities follow.[image]

> I think the proof has a mistake as we didnt use the fact that the
>   quadrilaterals are inscribed. So I am asking for both proof
>   verification and alternative proofs.

Comment: Are you using that $BF$ is parallel to $JG$ and that $FC$ is parallel to $GH$? If so, how did you prove that?

Comment: In general after a translation, a segment and its image are parallel. If we translate $GHIJ$ by $GF$,since the angles $HGJ$ and $CFB$ are equal the image of J will lie on FB and the image of H on FC.

Comment: So to answer you question I am not using $BF || JG$ or $FC||GH$.

Comment: Please say if you dont get my idea in the second diagram

Comment: Are you saying that $\angle{HGJ}=\angle{CFB}$ leads that $H'$ is on $FC$ and that $J'$ is on $BF$? I don't think so.

Comment: Yes, I see. This is the mistake it seems. Thanks